# Autofill an ACF field with another ACF field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to create clickable phone links for a store directory.

I'm using Elementor and ACF fields for the post template - but this doesn't seem to allow for clickable links unless you have 2 ACF fields (one for the text, one for the link).

Wondering if there is a way to autopopulate the second ACF field - ie. phone_number and phone_number_link so that the link grabs the first field and adds tel: to the front while deleting spaces in the field?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please also check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).